# How to get the Docker tag pull counts in JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: docker, count, tags, artifactory, jfrog-cli

Is it possible in Artifactory to get the number of total pull counts of the Docker tag?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Form the Artifactory UI click on `manifest.json` of a perticular tag. You will see download count there.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwhfx.png)